# i want to insert data randomly in PostgreSQL 500 K row?

Tags: sql, postgresql, random, sql-insert

```
INSERT INTO interactions(decription,drugcode,diseasecode,type)
VALUES ('xxas',224,56366,2);
```

my id auto increment
the type should be 1 or 2 just

my table

- id int autoincrement primary key
- description varchar(100) not null
- drug code int not null
- disease code int not null
- type int not null

value of type (1 or 2 ) just
how I can insert 500 k row random

Comment: the type should be 1 or 2 just

Comment: Can you please explain it more clearly?

Comment: i want to insert data randomly like 500 k rows
id int auti incremant
decription varchar(100)
drug code int
diseasecode int
type int put the value of type just be (1,2)

Comment: Pleae [edit] your question and explain where you stuck, what error appears and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use generate_series() for that.

```
INSERT INTO interactions (decription, drugcode, diseasecode, type)
select md5(random()::text),  -- some random text
       (random() * 999 + 1)::int, -- a random number between 1 and 1000
       (random() * 49 + 1)::int, -- a random number between 1 and 50
       (random() + 1)::int -- a random number between 1 and 2
from generate_series(1,500000);
```

Comment: @ahmadnoor: there was a wrong `,` in front of the `from`